# doubling the size of array with realloc()

Tags: c, memory, realloc

The following is an excerpt from my program.

```
void insert(int *pq,int key){
      if(MS==N){
           pq=(int*)realloc(pq,sizeof(int)*MS*2);
           MS*=2;
      }
      pq[++N]=INT_MIN;
      increase_key(pq,N,key); 
}

int* priority_queue(){
     int *heap=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
     MS=10;
     return heap;
}
```

While reallocating memory in insert function I am getting this error. I want to double the size of my array when it get filled completely.

```
(gdb) n
46             pq=(int*)realloc(pq,sizeof(int)*MS*2);
(gdb) n
*** Error in `/home/akhileshydv/Documents/Cprog/a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000602010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7ffff7a847e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x834aa)[0x7ffff7a904aa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x85ba9)[0x7ffff7a92ba9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x22f)[0x7ffff7a918ef]
/home/akhileshydv/Documents/Cprog/a.out[0x4007d5]
/home/akhileshydv/Documents/Cprog/a.out[0x4005e8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ffff7a2d830]
/home/akhileshydv/Documents/Cprog/a.out[0x4004e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 3414051                            /home/akhileshydv/Documents/Cprog/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:09 3414051                            /home/akhileshydv/Documents/Cprog/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:09 3414051                            /home/akhileshydv/Documents/Cprog/a.out
00602000-00623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff0000000-7ffff0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff0021000-7ffff4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff77f7000-7ffff780d000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 3936807                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff780d000-7ffff7a0c000 ---p 00016000 08:09 3936807                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7a0c000-7ffff7a0d000 rw-p 00015000 08:09 3936807                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7a0d000-7ffff7bcd000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 3938830                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7bcd000-7ffff7dcd000 ---p 001c0000 08:09 3938830                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7dcd000-7ffff7dd1000 r--p 001c0000 08:09 3938830                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7dd1000-7ffff7dd3000 rw-p 001c4000 08:09 3938830                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7ffff7dd3000-7ffff7dd7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7dd7000-7ffff7dfd000 r-xp 00000000 08:09 3938808                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7ffff7fdb000-7ffff7fde000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff5000-7ffff7ff8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff8000-7ffff7ffa000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00025000 08:09 3938808                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00026000 08:09 3938808                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a42428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Why I am getting this error? Please suggest any solution.

EDIT: I have made my 'pq' variable global as suggested in the comment section but, the problem still persists.

```
void priority_queue(){
     pq=malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
     MS=10;
}

void insert(int key){
      if(MS==N){
           pq=realloc(pq,sizeof(int)*MS*2);
           MS*=2;
      }
      pq[++N]=INT_MIN;
      increase_key(N,key); 
}
```

Comment: Please don't cast `malloc`'s return value

Comment: `pq=...` doesn't update caller's argument itself.

Comment: If I don't cast, I will get compile time error@Theophile Dano

Comment: Given `if(MS==N)`, I'd expect `pq[N++]=INT_MIN;` instead of `++N`.  Post declaration, initial value of `MS`.

Comment: @AkhileshYadav "Compile time error" implies you are not using a C compiler but something else.

Comment: see this reference [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @AkhileshYadav When BLUEPIXY said "doesn't update", they meant that nothing gets updated *in the code that called `insert`*.  And that's very likely what your problem is, since on the next call to `insert`, you end up writing into (and overflowing), the old, unresized (and probably deallocated) buffer.

Comment: @chux I am compiling this using ubuntu terminal with command 'gcc <filename>.C'

Comment: @AkhileshYadav Use `.c` (lowercase c).  `.C` is probably telling compiler to assume C++.

Comment: If `realloc` is successful, old space(It is the area that the caller's pointer points to.) will be released. If you try to use it on the next call, it will be reported as an illegal area. Also, the new area, which is the return value of `realloc`, will no longer be referenced from anywhere after the scope of the function is over.

Comment: @AkhileshYadav You still haven't followed chux's suggestion about `++N` vs. `N++`.

Comment: @SteveSummit my initial value of N=-1, so I had to pre-increment to make it 0 first and then insert.

Comment: Instead of guessing or randomly trying different solutions, use valgrind to diagnose out-of-bounds modifications when they occur. And then use a debugger f necessary to figure out why.

Comment: @AkhileshYadav Starting at 0, and using postfix `++` as you're filling the array, is generally much cleaner.  It's the C Way.  I recommend it.

Comment: @Steve Summit You are right. It worked when I took N=0 and used post-increment operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

1. You need an extra level of indirection on `pq` in the `insert` function - if you update the value with `realloc`, that new value of `pq` won't be updated in the function that called `insert`.
2. Never assign the result of `realloc` directly to the original pointer - if `realloc` fails, it will return `NULL`, and you'll wind up losing your reference to the previously allocated memory, leading to a memory leak.  Assign the result to a temporary, check the temporary to make sure the `realloc` succeeded, *then* update your original pointer and size variables.
3. If you intend for `N` to be the index of the *next available element* in `*pq`, then you should update it as `N++`, not `++N`.  If you use `++N`, then `N` is the index the *last written element* (and you skip over element 0, and you risk indexing one past the last element in the array).  Based on how the `insert` function is written, it looks like you intend for `N` to represent the next available element in `*pq`, so you should update it as `N++`.
4. Don't cast the result of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` - if your compiler complains, then you're compiling this code *as C++*, not C.  If you intend for this code to be compiled **as C++**, then you shouldn't be using `malloc` at all, but rather a `vector` or some other standard container.  If you intend for this code to be compiled **as C**, then lose the casts on `malloc` and `realloc` and double-check your compiler settings.

Putting this all together:

```
void insert(int **pq, int key){
      if(MS == N) {
           int *tmp = realloc(*pq, sizeof **pq * MS * 2); // sizeof **pq == sizeof (int)
           if (tmp)
           {
             *pq = tmp;
             MS *= 2;
           }
           else
           {
             // realloc failed, original buffer is still intact.  Handle
             // as appropriate.
           }
      }
      (*pq)[N++] = INT_MIN; // parens are required here
      increase_key(*pq, N, key); // assuming increase_key does not need to modify pq
}
```

And you'd call it as:

```
int *q = malloc( sizeof *q * INITIAL_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS );
...
insert( &q, keyval );
```

Comment: "if your compiler complains, you're compiling this code as C++. If you intend for this code to be compiled as C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` at all".  I like that syllogism. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yup.  As I've said before, the best way to avoid problems with memory management is to avoid memory management.

Answer (score 0):

If N start with -1 then you should try:

```
void insert(int key){
      if(MS==N+1){
           pq=realloc(pq,sizeof(int)*MS*2);
           MS*=2;
      }
      pq[++N]=INT_MIN;
      increase_key(N,key); 
}
```

But I agree that it would be better to start with 0.